# AD FS doesn't do MFA enrollment properly for non-English browsers

Tags: entra-id, adfs, localization, azure-mfa, multi-factor-authentication

We have an on-premise AD FS 2019 server for SSO, connected to Azure AD (sigh, now Entra ID) for MFA. We closely followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa) when setting things up, and it has worked well for some time now.

But this was for employees, all of whom are US-based native English speakers. We are a small university, and we recently started bringing students on board for MFA. This includes some students who are not native English speakers. From what I can see, the default documentation is incomplete or broken for these people.

Specifically, in the section titled ["Catch the error and update the page text"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa#catch-the-error-and-update-the-page-text), the javascript provided by the documentation only looks for the English-language version of the original error.<sup>*</sup> This is true even if you manually change the URL to show a different language. Worse, there's no easy way I can see to discover how AD FS localizes this content for other cultures.

We can't be the first to run into this. I know Microsoft would prefer more people go all-in with Entra ID, but I also know there are still lots of on-prem AD environments out there. And since we could (in theory) accept an international student from just about anywhere, I don't want to play whack-a-mole with which languages I check for.

What are other people who need to support international users doing for MFA enrollment with on-prem AD FS and Entra MFA?

---

<sup>* Side note, but the javascript from the documentation also only provides English-language feedback for the user. This is less of an issue for us since we expect students to have basic English skills (must pass the [TOEFL](https://www.ets.org/toefl.html)), but could be problematic at other organizations.</sup>